# QT - Identificar coordenadas de uma imagem em uma QLabel de tamanho diferente?

Tags: c++, imagem, qt, eventos-do-mouse, gui

Olá, recentemente estive com uma duvida sobre como rastrear coordenadas de uma QLabel utilizando o cursor do mouse. Funcionou bem pelo que eu pensava em fazer. O que pretendo fazer é o  seguinte, tenho uma imagem que projeto na tela através de uma QLabel, incluí uma função para rastrear as coordenadas desta QLabel. 
Abaixo um PrintScreen da tela do meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu precisarei dos valores destas coordenadas corretas da imagem para trabalhar nela futuramente, mas os unicos valores que o cursor obtém são os valores de pixel do tamanho da minha QLabel. 
Por exemplo, a QLabel possui tamanho 551x461, já a imagem possui tamanho 960x720. Existe alguma maneira de eu conseguir capturar as coordenadas de pixel corretas da imagem na QLabel com tamanho distintos? Existe algum método de conversão destes dados em QT? Compreendo que este problema parece ser complicado demais, mas achei que nao custaria tentar.

Abaixo o código da captura do das Coordenadas:

```
void mainwindow::on_ButtonAddFileira_clicked(){

this->pTimer.disconnect();
QImage image;

image.load("C:/Users/Syn/Desktop/TCC/Fotos Bolsão FEI/02 Bolsao_Cheio_Foreground.jpg");

//image = MatToQImage(this->ImagemBase.capturaImgBuffer());

ui->labelScreen->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
ui->labelScreen->setScaledContents(true);

connect(&cursorTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(cursor_timer_timeout()));
cursorTimer.start(50);

}
```

labelScreen é a QLabel de Display da imagem, e no código abaixo label_X e label_Y sao as labels das coordenadas na tela.

```
void mainwindow::cursor_timer_timeout(){

QPoint cursorPos = ui->labelScreen->mapFromGlobal( QCursor::pos() );

int x = cursorPos.x();
int y = cursorPos.y();

ui->label_X->setNum(x);
ui->label_Y->setNum(y);
}
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda e atenção, qualquer pequena ajuda será bem vinda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem o que você quer dizer com "coordenadas corretas", você simplesmente gostaria de obter as coordenadas na "imagem real" (sem ajuste), e não na imagem "espremida" (a que foi ajustada/escalonada quando colocada dentro do `QLabel`).

Não sei se você percebeu o que fez, mas você simplesmente indicou para que o `QLAbel` ajuste automaticamente a imagem nas dimensões dele ao fazer:

```
ui->labelScreen->setScaledContents(true);
```

Como o `QLabel` é um componente visual (herdado de `QWidget`), o seu método de captura do mouse retorna as coordenadas no componente visual, não na imagem. Por isso, essas coordenadas estão limitadas às dimensões do `QLabel`.

Você poderia tentar calcular o "desajuste", **se o seu `QLabel` tivesse a mesma [razão de aspecto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propor%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_tela) da imagem** (o que não é o caso - não sei se foi intencional ou não, mas talvez tenha sido erro da sua parte). A sua imagem tem uma razão de aspecto 4:3 (também chamado de 1,33). Dividindo a largura pela altura, tem-se:

```
960/720 = 1,33  ===>  1,33:1 ou 4:3
```

Essa é a razão de aspecto tradicional, quadradona, utilizada nas TVs antigas, por exemplo. Há uma outra razão de aspecto famosa chamada 16:9 (ou 1,77:1) ou, como é mais popularmente conhecida, [*Widescreen*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widescreen) (as telas mais largas utilizadas no cinema e TV mais modernos e nos vídeos FullHD, em que a largura é *quase* o dobro da altura).

Bom, o seu `QLabel` tem uma razão de aspecto bizarra:

```
551/461 = 1,195  ===>  1,195:1
```

Está bem mais próximo de uma área quadrada (razão de aspecto 1:1) do que a imagem original, e por isso que eu imaginei que você simplesmente não tomou cuidado na definição dessa razão de aspecto.

A grande sacada é que, não importa o tamanho do seu `QLabel`, você pode calcular o valor do pixel original fazendo uma simples [regra de três](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regra_de_tr%C3%AAs). Por exemplo, se o seu `QLabel` tiver as dimensões 614x461 (agora sim, no aspecto 4:3), para um dado `x` (coordenada de largura) ou `y` (coordenada de altura), basta fazer:

Para o x:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para o y:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Observe que você poderia fazer essa mesma conta para cada um dos
>   componentes das coordenadas (x e y) *sem se preocupar com a razão de
>   aspecto*, e ainda assim obteria uma aproximação das coordenadas reais.
>   A questão é que mantendo a razão de aspecto igual essa aproximação é
>   simplesmente melhor, *pois não ocorre distorção* na imagem conforme ela
>   é escalonada para "caber" numa área menor do que a original.

Comment: Obrigadoo, ajudou muito. Consegui pegar as coordenadas da imagem apenas pela regra de três. Realmente, nao levei em consideração a razao de aspecto, sou iniciante em manipulação de imagens, por isso nao fazia idéia deste conceito, mais um aprendizado adquirido. a Label possuia este tamanho bizarro porq eu nao queria criar uma janela mto espaçosa do meu projeto, ae criei o tamanho da label compativel com a tela. Novamente, muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo!